# Getting 401 HTTP error during deployment only

Tags: django, angular, apache, amazon-ec2, web-deployment

I made a website using Django and Angular. I deployed the app using the instructions from this link: https://medium.com/saarthi-ai/ec2apachedjango-838e3f6014ab

**Problem**
When I ran the app locally it works fine.
[image]

**But,** during deployment I am getting 401 error, I don't understand why.
[image]

The deployment is done in the Amazon AWS EC2 instance using an Apache webserver. The authentication used is [django-rest-knox](http://james1345.github.io/django-rest-knox/)

P.S: I also checked the admin panel and the token of the user is added.

Comment: Did you set your `ALLOWED_HOSTS`? Also what happens if you try ec2 instance dns, rather then its ip address?

Comment: Yes, I set allowed host to the EC2's IP. They gave me only the IP for the EC2 instance.

Comment: Hello @Yogesh Have you solved this issue?

Comment: @Marcin was right, later I asked my manager to give the DNS of the machine and made https (not http) request, and it worked.